# View Asterisk CLI on PHP remote site

Tags: php, curl, command-line-interface, asterisk, agi

Recently i was instructed to make a tool to debug CLI commands and responses from asterisk in a remote server to be displayed on a webpage.

I looked into the ARI options but the system im using is pbxware and they only have the AGI commands available.

Anyone knows a different way to do this or maybe with the AGI options.?

Answer (score 0):

Check logger.conf option. It can save cli output to file.

After that you have orginize file read using php.

For example you can use freepbx asterisk CLI module.